# How use `echo` in a command in docker-compose.yml to handle a colon (":") sign?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-machine

Here is my `docker-compose.yml`,

```
elasticsearch:
  ports:
  - 9200:9200/tcp
  image: elasticsearch:2.4
 volumes:
  - /data/elasticsearch/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
 command: /bin/bash -c “echo 'http.cors.enabled: true' > /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
```

it throws the error:

> Activating (yaml: [] mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 7, column 49

Looks as if I cannot use the colon sign `:` in `command`, is this true?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The colon is how YAML introduces a dictionary.  If you have it in a value, you just need to quote the value, for example like this:

```
image: "elasticsearch:2.4"
```

Or by using one of the block scalar operators, like this:

```
command: >
  /bin/bash -c “echo 'http.cors.enabled: true' > /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
```

For more information, take a look at the [YAML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YAML) page on Wikipedia.  You can always use something like [this online YAML parser](http://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/) to test out your YAML syntax.

Properly formatted, your first document should look something like:

```
elasticsearch:
  ports:
    - 9200:9200/tcp
  image: "elasticsearch:2.4"
  volumes:
    - /data/elasticsearch/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
  command: >
    /bin/bash -c “echo 'http.cors.enabled: true' > /usr/share/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
```

(The indentation of the list markers (`-`) from the key isn't strictly necessary, but I find that it helps make things easier to read)

A docker container can only run a single `command`.  If you want to run multiple commands, put them in a shell script and copy that into the image.